# Scaling android application for different displays with same proportions

Tags: scale

How can i scale my application on different displays (sizes) in same manner and proportions?
(I tried compatible-mode, different styles with different font sizes, but it did not suit me)

Answer (score 0):

When i got task for scaling application that was built for Nexus7 (7 inches) to device with 14' display after many hours researching i found best way to do that. I override standard configuration and displayMetrics while my Application is initializing. Look at the code sample:

```
            //change dinsity for xlarge with mdpi displays for same proportions as Nexus7
        if (context.getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.bool_screen_xlarge)) {
//            final int densityValue = DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW; //120
//            final int densityValue = DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM; //160
//            final int densityValue = 213; //213 Nexus 7 2012
//            final int densityValue = DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH; //240
            final int densityValue = DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH; //320
            final float densityFactor = (float) densityValue / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT; //1.5f for example

            Resources resources = context.getResources();
            DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
            Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
            configuration.fontScale = densityFactor;
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) configuration.densityDpi = densityValue;
            displayMetrics.xdpi = densityValue * (displayMetrics.xdpi / displayMetrics.densityDpi);
            displayMetrics.ydpi = densityValue * (displayMetrics.ydpi / displayMetrics.densityDpi);
            displayMetrics.density = densityFactor;
            displayMetrics.densityDpi = densityValue;
            displayMetrics.scaledDensity = densityFactor;
        }
```

This code you should put to Application::onCreate() method.
R.bool.bool_screen_xlarge - is variable in different resource directories (res/value, res/value-xlarge-mdpi and so on) for simple recognizing current display metrics.